# How can I add a handler to jquery UI dialog close event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to execute some script on closing of jquery ui dialog. Does jquery dialog has a 'close' event for which I can add a handler to execute my script? If it exists can you please show me how to do it with an example

Comment: Please consider reading the documentation first. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can bind `close event` like,

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Read [close-event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close)

Answer (score 4):

You want the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) event, which executes after the dialog has been destroyed:

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
    close: function(e, ui) {
        // do your thing...
    }
});
```

There is also the [`beforeClose`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose) event which fires as soon as the close button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [beforeClose](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose), or the [close](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) event for that purpose (depending on your needs).

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
  close: function( event, ui ) {
         alert("oh my god, I'm closing");
         }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use..

```
 $("#dialogboxid").bind("dialogclose",function(e){ // do your stuff.
 //your code goes here
 });
```